# Uncaught ReferenceError: form is not defined

Tags: javascript, forms

Can't for the life of me figure this out. any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is the message I receive in Google Chrome when I test the script:

Navigated to http://localhost/contact.php
form2.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: form is not definedform2.js:2 validatecontact.php:24 onsubmit
Navigated to http://localhost/contact.php

My contact.php file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="form2.js"></script>



<?php require 'Includes/Header.php'; ?>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="contact-form">
        <h5>Contact Form</h5>
    <form name="contact" form method="post" action="contact.php" 
    onsubmit="return validate(contact)">

        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name">

        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email">

        <label for="message">Message:</label>
        <textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea>


        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>         
            <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    </div>


   <?php require 'Includes/Footer.php'; ?>
```

My form2.js file:

```
    function validate(contact){
    var name = form.name.value;
    var email = form.email.value;
    var message = form.message.value;

    if (name.length == 0 || name.length > 200)
    {alert ("You must enter a name.");
    return false;
    }

    if (email.length == 0 || email.length > 200)
    {alert ("You must enter a email.");
    return false;
    }

    if (message.length == 0)
    {alert ("You must enter a message.");
    return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect `form` to exist?

Comment: You have a `form` attribute in the form tag...?

Answer (score 6):

form is a javascript object. That object does not exist within this file, which is why the error is being thrown. If you want to validate this form, you need to get a reference to it from the DOM first, using document.contact.

```
function validate(contact){
  var form = document.contact,
      name = form.name.value,
      email = form.email.value,
      message = form.message.value;

  if (name.length == 0 || name.length > 200) {
    alert ("You must enter a name.");
    return false;
  }

  if (email.length == 0 || email.length > 200) {
    alert ("You must enter a email.");
    return false;
  }

  if (message.length == 0) {
    alert ("You must enter a message.");
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try using jquery by adding

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"  src="./jquery-1.9.1.js" />
```

to the header (you will have to download it or then add:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to get the latest)
then in your function get the values of the input fieds as follow:

```
var name = $('#name').value;
var email = $('#email').value;
var message = $('#message').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Access forms like this

```
<form action="#" name="test_form">
    <input name="firstname" value="hello world"/>
  </form>

var valueOfInput = document.test_form.firstname.value

you can also go like documents.forms["test_form"].elements
```

so maybe passing in document.contact can help ...

otherwise look at libraries like jQuery which give you a nice api to access DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

The error is what it says. You don't have a `form` variable defined (From what you've shared).

Also, it looks like you're trying to validate your form by accessing the values of the input fields. Here is how you should / could do it -

```
function validate(contact){
   var name = document.getElementsByName('name')[0].value;
   // You can also do the following
   // var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
   // var name = document.forms['contact'].elements['name'].value;

   var email = document.getElementsByName('email')[0].value;
   var message = document.getElementsByName('message')[0].value;

   if (name.length == 0 || name.length > 200)
   {
     alert ("You must enter a name.");
     return false;
   }

   if (email.length == 0 || email.length > 200)
   {  
      alert ("You must enter a email.");
      return false;
   }

  if (message.length == 0)
  {  
    alert ("You must enter a message.");
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, Aswin. Thank you. And many thanks to all the other contributors too. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sure. You can always mark it as answer if it works, you know. :)